# How do I upload my own python package and its dependencies as layer to AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have my own python package, let's call it `my_package`.

One of the dependencies for `my_package` is a different library - let's call it `abc`.  `abc` is available to download via pip.

I am trying to create an AWS Lambda layer that has both `my_package` and `abc` bundled.

I have tried the following:

1. When creating a zip for the layer, i `pip install --target target_dir ./my_package abc`.  So they are both included.
2. Including `abc` as dependency in `setup.py` for `my_package` so its installed when `my_package` is installed.
3. Both 1 and 2 at the same time.

But every time when I end up running my lambda function with the layer I get the error

```
errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'abc.lib'"
```

The only way ive been able to get this to work is to add `abc` in the `requirements.txt` for each lambda function I have and building the function that way.  I'm confused why that works when its really just `my_package` that needs it.

What is the correct way to create and upload a my own package and its dependencies as a layer so i dont need to add requirements to each lambda function on top of the layer?

I dont think it matters, but 'abc' is actually `pyarrow` in case that makes a difference.

Comment: This looks like the structure of your layer is not correct. How did you structure the data in the layer? Check the folder structure for layer in Python here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html

Comment: Yeah I’ve been using that but it’s not clear to me how to manage my packages dependencies from it. I have several layers that work but they are all basically standalone and can be installed from pip. 

Now that I think about it maybe it is the pyarrow since I included requests the same way and it works as expected.

Comment: Example of someone deploying pyarrow to a Lambda layer [here](https://medium.com/@stevenrfraser7/compiling-a-slim-version-of-pyarrow-for-lambda-af995c52c6f0), plus reducing its size.